# Inlining assembly in Intel Compiler- FASM?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, intel

If you wish to write inline assembly within C++ (when compiling C++ with the Intel Compiler) which assembly syntax do you use? Is it FASM/NASM or MASM? and does this matter which OS you are on (or does the Intel compiler abstract that difference away)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-win/GUID-5100C4FC-BC2F-4E36-943A-120CFFFB4285.htm), The Intel® C++ Compiler supports both Microsoft-style and GNU-like style inline assembly:

> ### Inline Assembly
>
> #### Microsoft* Style Inline Assembly
>
> The Intel® C++ Compiler supports Microsoft-style inline assembly. See
> the Microsoft documentation for the proper syntax.
>
> #### GNU*-like Style Inline Assembly (IA-32 architecture and Intel® 64 architecture only)
>
> The Intel® C++ Compiler supports GNU-like style inline assembly. The
> syntax is as follows:
>
> ```
> asm-keyword [ volatile-keyword ] ( asm-template [ asm-interface ] ) ;
> ```
>
> #### NOTE
>
> The Intel® C++ Compiler supports gcc-style inline ASM if the assembler code uses AT&T*
> System V/386 syntax.